# what is the shortcut key of kotlin for loop in Intellij?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

when we working with java in **Intellij** we have `fori` key for auto complete a for loop but i could not find the same shortcut key for that when working with Kotlin in Intellij .

actually i have tried and found `iter` shortcut but it is for `foreach` i want auto complete of some thing  like `for (i in 0 until 10 step 3)` .

can you help me find the correct key for that

Answer (score 3):

I think `iter` is the closest you get out of the box; it is is defined in the live templates as:

```
for ($VAR$ in $ITERABLE$) {
$END$
}
```

Go to preferences then search for live, this will show you all the live templates.  If you then open the Kotlin section in the tree on the right
you can make a copy of `iter` (using the copy icon) then you can edit it in the pane at the bottom. Call the copied template `iteru` and amend it to something like

```
for ($VAR$ in $START$ until $ENDV$ step $STEP$) {
$END$
}
```

If `iter` is displaying `foreach` it might be that intellij thinks the source file type is something other than Kotlin.

Comment: i do not want this template

Comment: I have updated my answer to hopefully better reflect your needs.

Comment: how can i define sth like this

Comment: Open preferences and search for "live" open the Kotlin branch on the tree, select `iter` and click copy, you edit it in place.